# Shell script — weird behaviour after concatenating string with variables

Tags: shell, sh

I am reading a `.properties` file from my shell script.
I wanted to read some value for some key and after that want to append it in between some string but the output is weird.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script used to read Property File
FILE_NAME="Test.properties"
prop_value=$(cat ${FILE_NAME} | grep Address)
echo "ABC${prop_value}DEF"
```

my Test.properties is like this

```
Name=Pravin
Age=25
Address=Mumbai
asd=asd
```

After executing this script I am expecting

```
ABCAddress=MumbaiDEF
```

but I am getting output like

```
DEFAddress=Mumbai
```

What would be the problem here?

If I define any variable in a script it works, but when I read it from file using command expansion it doesn't work.

Comment: Your file is in DOS format. It contains carriage returns, which send the cursor to the beginning of the line when printed.

Comment: BTW, you've got other bugs in here that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch.

Comment: Amongst other issues with the code, see [UUoC — Useless Use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).  I'm sure this is a duplicate; finding the duplicate will be harder (and probably not worth the effort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trim carriage returns from a variable on expansion, you can use `${varname%$'\r'}`. Thus:

```
echo "ABC${prop_value%$'\r'}DEF"
```

Better would be to save your properties file as a native Unix text file, which contains no carriage returns at all.